# How to render a paragraph onto a surface in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I've made a fully functioning main menu with buttons where one button take you to the game and another button that takes you to the instruction page.

However, in my instructions page I can only write a one line sentence. If I add multiple lines it shows squares in the middle.

What I want achieve is to write a multi-line paragraph onto the screen for displaying some instruction, game information, etc.

Here es a screen shot of my current game GUI:
[image: Game GUI]

And this is the relevant code I have so far:

```
def text_objects(text, font):
   textSurface = font.render(text, True, (0,0,0))
   return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()


def ParagraphText(text, font):
   ParagraphSize = (600,500)
   FontSize = font.get_height()

   ParagraphSurf = pygame.Surface(ParagraphSize)

   ParagraphSurf.fill(WHITE)
   ParagraphSurf.set_colorkey(WHITE)

   SplitLines = text.splitlines()

   CentreText = (ParagraphSize[1] - len(SplitLines)*(FontSize + 1)//2)

   for idx, line in enumerate(SplitLines):
       currentTextline = font.render(text, False, (0, 0, 0))
       currentPostion = (0, idx * FontSize + CentreText)
       ParagraphSurf.blit(currentTextline, currentPostion)

   return ParagraphSurf, ParagraphSize



def Instructions():
   paragraph = """Your are the last surviving rhino. Your horn
   is worth millions! Right now you are trapped in a zoo and
   waiting to be slaughtered for your horn. But you can't give
   up! Escape from the tribesmen and zoo security so you can
   enjoy your life as a free being once again"""

   screen.blit(pygame.image.load("background0.jpg").convert(), (0,0))
   InstructionsFont = pygame.font.SysFont("elephant",15)
   TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("Instructions", InstructionsFont)
   TextRect.center = ((screen_width/2),(screen_height/6))
   screen.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

   ParagraphText(paragraph,InstructionsFont)

   intro = True

   while intro:
       for event in pygame.event.get():
           if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
               pygame.quit()
               quit()

       Buttons("BACK",100,500,120,50,TURQUOISE,DARK_TURQUOISE,"back")

       pygame.display.update()
       clock.tick(15)
```

Comment: I think you will have to provide each line separately.

Comment: I agree with @jonrsharpe

Comment: btw: now, in every second you repeat 15 times: declare paragraph text, load image, create font, get surf and rect, center it, create button - but you can do it only once, before `while intro`.

Comment: sorry i dont quite understan what you mean.

Comment: `Instructions` can look like this: http://pastebin.com/8UFqkXVv . If you don't have animations then it can look like this: http://pastebin.com/bVPGsjuT

Comment: Ok thanks that makes sense! i was repeating everything 15 seconds which is a waste of cpu performance etc... thanks for clearing that up

Comment: You need to set `TextSurf` and `TextRect` to the value returned by of the `ParagraphText()` function: `TextSurf, TextRect = ParagraphText(paragraph, InstructionsFont)`

Comment: I think i've done that before but nothing showed up on my screen when i went to instructions

Answer (score 1):

The [`render()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html#pygame.font.Font.render) method of a [`pygame.font.Font`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html#pygame.font.Font) object can only blit single line text, as stated in the [documentation](https://www.pygame.org/docs).

To work around this you have to adapt your `text_objects()` function to draw each line of the passed in text string separately onto the appropriate position:

1. Create a new surface onto which the whole paragraph will be drawn. To fake a transparent surface use Pygame's [`set_colorkey()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.set_colorkey) method. <sup>1)</sup>
2. Split the text into several lines of characters using Python's built-in [`splitlines()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines) method.
3. Compute an optional offset value if you want to align (e.g. center) the text vertically inside the paragraph surface.
4. Loop (i.e. enumerate) over the split lines:

   - Render the current line of characters onto a dummy surface. <sup>1)</sup>
   - Calculate the position of this line to fit into a paragraph style.
   - Blit the dummy surface onto the main paragraph surface.
5. Draw the paragraph surface onto the main screen or return it with other parameters.

Now it´s time implement this:

```
def text_objects(text, font):
    paragraphSize = (xsize, ysize)
    fontSize = font.get_height()

    # Step 1
    paragraphSurface = pygame.Surface(paragraphSize ) 

    #Set colorkey to fake transparent paragraph surface
    paragraphSurface.fill((255, 255, 255))
    paragraphSurface.set_colorkey((255, 255, 255))

    # Step 2
    splitLines = text.splitlines() 

    # Step 3: center the text vertically 
    offSet = (paragraphSize[1] - len(splitLines) * (fontSize + 1)) // 2 

    #Step 4
    for idx, line in enumerate(splitLines):
        currentTextline = font.render(line, False, (0, 0, 0))
        currentPostion = (0, idx * fontSize + offSet)
        paragraphSurface.blit(currentTextline, currentPostion)

    #Step 5
    return paragraphSurface, paragraphSize
```

---

If you want to center each line in the text, don't set the `x`-coordinate of the `currentPostion` to `0` but use the following calculation:

```
#center paragraph
currentPostion = ((paragraphSize[0] - currentTextline.get_width()) // 2, #x-coordinate
                  idx * fontSize + offSet) #y-coordinate
```

[image: sample: center text]

or right align:

```
#right align paragraph
currentPostion = (paragraphSize[0] - currentTextline.get_width(), #x-coordinate
                  idx * fontSize + offSet) #y-coordinate
```

[image: sample: right align]

<sup>1)</sup> *Please note that setting the `antialias` parameter to `true` when rendering a line, can have bad effects because of the set color-key of the paragraph surface!*

I hope this helps you :)

Comment: Hi thanks for ur time and effort to help me but i've got a few questions. What does idx mean and when u use font.render(line...) what does it have line and not the paragraph of text instead?

Comment: im asking this because currently i've used what you taught me to make a seperate function called paragraphtext(). its got the same arguments are the text objects and i called it into my Instructions function as paragraphtext(paragraph, InstructionsFont) but nothing shows up?

Comment: Sorry for my late reply! `idx` is the index returned by Pythons [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) function. Could you please post your updated code, so I can see what's going on?